# Select all second highest values only from temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Using T-SQL (SQL Server 2008 R2), I'm trying to list only the rows with the second highest value in a particular column from a temp table and then place the results into a new temp table.  The PK is the `ID`, which can have increasing version numbers and then unique codes.

Example:

```
 ID | Name| Version | Code
------------------------
 1  | A   | 1       | 10
 1  | A   | 2       | 20
 1  | A   | 3       | NULL
 2  | B   | 1       | 40
 2  | B   | 2       | 50
 2  | C   | 1       | 60
```

The desired outcome of the query is

```
ID |  Version | Code
------------------------
1  |  2       | 20
2  |  1       | 40
```

To achieve this I need the below query to be adapted to pull the second highest value as long as the result gives a version number greater than 1.  These results come from a temp table and will then be placed into a final results temp table.  **EDIT: Please note this will be applied over 33000 rows of data so I would prefer something neater than INSERT VALUES. Thanks.**

Current query:

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,Version
    ,Code
INTO 
    #table2
FROM
    #table1

SELECT * 
FROM #table2
WHERE Version > 1
ORDER BY ID asc

DROP TABLE #table1
DROP TABLE #table2
```

I have tried running the where clause `WHERE Version < (SELECT MAX(VERSION) FROM #TABLE 2)` but this has no effect, presumably due to the unique code values and in any case wouldn't work where I have more than 3 Versions.

Ideas would be gratefully received.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i HAVE TEST THE BELOW CODE AND IT IS GIVING OUTPUT AS PER The YOUR desired outcome of the query is

```
SELECT ID,Name,[Version],Code
FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY [Version] DESC) AS RNK,*
        FROM
            (
                SELECT 1 ID, 'A' Name ,1 [Version] ,10 Code
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 1, 'A', 2 ,20
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 1, 'A', 3 ,30
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 1, 'A', 4 ,NULL
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 2, 'B', 1 ,40
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 2, 'B', 2 ,50
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 2, 'C', 1 ,60
            )B
        )BASE
WHERE RNK =2
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but unfortunately not practical due to the volume of data I am dealing with in reality (33000 rows).  I have updated the question.

Comment: As per you table you can try this:          

SELECT ID,Name,[Version],Code
FROM
(
 SELECT ID,Name,[Version],Code,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY [Version] DESC) AS RNK
 FROM [Your table name]
)base
WHERE RNK = 2

Comment: Spot on - that was the solution which I have adapted to my desired outcome (partitioning by Version instead). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If your primary key is only ID, you have duplicate rows. So I assume your primary key is something else, for example ID, Version, Name. You have two rows with the same ID and same Version, what kind of rule do you want to apply on this ? Lowest number ?

I made an example that does kind of what you want:

First declare the necessary tables:

```
declare @table1 table (
    Id int,
    Name nvarchar(20),
    [Version] int,
    Code int
)

insert into @table1 values (1,'A',1,10),(1,'A',2,20),(1,'A',3,30),(1,'A',4,NULL)
                          ,(2,'B',1,40),(2,'B',2,50),(2,'C',1,60);
```

And then the query to get the results:

```
with HighestVersions (Id, MaxVersion) As 
(
    select Id, max(version) from @table1 group by Id
)
select
    t1.Id,
    t1.[Version],
    min(t1.Code) as Code
from
    @table1 t1
    inner join
        HighestVersions hv
        on
            hv.Id = t1.Id
            and (hv.MaxVersion-1) = t1.[Version]
group by
    t1.Id
    ,t1.[Version]
```

I had to do a little dirty trick with the outermost select, this is because of the duplicate 'Id' and 'Version'. Else you would have gotten two rows with ID = 2, Version = 1

If you want to remove the NULL value you can change the WITH part (according to your last edit):

```
with HighestVersions (Id, MaxVersion) As 
(
    select Id, max(version) from @table1 where Code is not null group by Id
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Joeri - you're right regarding the PK... the ID is the only PK for another table which I will be eventually joining these results on to so that's probably the confusion.  Nonetheless it will be the PK of the resulting table2 table that I requested above.   

Your solution won't quite work for me because I am in reality dealing with 33k+ rows of data so I need something a little neater than inserting all those values!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @List TABLE (ID int, Name char(1), Version int, Code int NULL)

INSERT INTO @List
VALUES
(1, 'A', 1, 10),
(1, 'A', 2, 20),
(1, 'A', 3, 30),
(1, 'A', 4, NULL),
(2, 'B', 1, 40),
(2, 'B', 2, 50),
(2, 'C', 1, 60)


SELECT
    ID, Name, Version, Code
FROM
   (
    SELECT
        *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name ORDER BY Version DESC) Rn
    FROM @List
   ) a
WHERE
    a.Rn = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but unfortunately not practical due to the volume of data I am dealing with in reality (33000 rows).  I have updated the question.